# Service with threads. How to restart some threads after delay?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I'm trying to do this with Handler, but my Handler want be static, so I can't use `startThread` method.

This is Handler

```
private class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Integer tmp = msg.what;
        Log.d(Tag, tmp.toString());
        switch (msg.what) {
        case THREAD_SYNC_START:
            startSyncThread();
            break;
        case THREAD_SYNC_STOP:
            mSyncThread.interrupt();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my service's method for starting thread

```
private void startSyncThread() {
    if (mSyncThread != null) mSyncThread.interrupt();
    mSyncThread = new SyncThread();
    mSyncThread.start();
}
```

Thread send message to handler

```
        mServiceHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(THREAD_SYNC_START, 2000);
```

I don't need any leaks, so I'm looking for right way to go this task.

Comment: Why do you want to build your own Handler? Is the AsyncTask not good for your needs?

Comment: @SimonZettervall How can be AsyncTask restarted after dalay? In my case "**Thread** send _Message_ to **Handler**" -> "**Handler** restart **Thread**"

Comment: That is up to you to "restart". There is no such thing in threads. You can start new thread, pause thread, or stop/finish a thread. Resume operation depends on your code. You have to store data computed so far when thread stops (aplication pause). On start, you pass that data to thread again. And your algorithm has to skip already processed parts to continue from point when you stopped last time.

Comment: @Pihhan I need start thread, it doing something, stops, then service automatically after some time start this thread again. How can service start thread after some delay?

Comment: Handler have by default current thread configured as destination of message. You can then handler.runDelayed(new Runnable() { this.StartNewThread(); }, 2000); This will immediately continue, after two seconds will start runnable from current thread. Use AsyncTask to start computation in new thread. You can use AsyncTask.cancel() method, just keep reference to it. From onCancelled() you can again use handler to runDelayed().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some sample code where you use an AsyncTask instead and let it's callback determine if you are supposed to create a new AsyncTask. Please tell me if it is wrong.

TestFragment:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private Handler mHandler;

    /*
     * Skipping most code and I will only show you the most essential.
     */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        startAsyncTask(0);
    }

    private void startAsyncTask(long milisecondsToDelay) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestAsyncTask testAsyncTask = new TestAsyncTask(new FragmentCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTaskDone() {
                        startAsyncTask(1000);
                    }
                });

                testAsyncTask.execute();
            }
        }, milisecondsToDelay);

    }

    public interface FragmentCallback {
        public void onTaskDone();
    }
}
```

TestAsyncTask:

```
public class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private boolean mShouldCreateNewAsyncTask;
    private FragmentCallback mFragmentCallback;

    public TestAsyncTask(FragmentCallback fragmentCallback) {
        mFragmentCallback = fragmentCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /*
         * Do your loop or whatever and when you need to restart it set
         * mShouldCreateNewAsyncTask = true and return null.
         */

        mShouldCreateNewAsyncTask = true;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (mShouldCreateNewAsyncTask) {
            mFragmentCallback.onTaskDone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this works and can be solution for this question, but I wrote Handler the right way